# Converting String to Date

Tags: apex, json, datetime

I have date format which is returned from JSON which i get in String, how do I convert it to Salesforce date format ? Does anyone have knowledge which date format is this ? Following is the date format. /Date(-62135568000000-0800)/

> Datetime format - /Date(-62135568000000-0800)/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658914/cant-parse-json-date-from-sql-server-in-javascript

Comment: This kinda looks like Datetime in ticks format. 1 tick is 20 seconds